# Align moving audio synced bars to circle inside canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to align bars which are synced to music (therefore moving) to a circle on a canvas. I already have the sync to music and make a round circle with it ready.

Right now I am trying to rotate them so it looks good, however since this is my first attempt with canvas I am failing miserably..

Here is the code [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidReinberger/f8c8b1687bc34c02fd24#file-visualize).

If i run it with the `c.rotate(bar[i].rot);` it gets all scrambled...

Please can you help me out with this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing :
- Clear the whole canvas on each frame. It's too complicated, and performance-wise not worth the trouble to erase only what's required.

Second :
The Canvas's RenderingContext2D, is a context, meaning it's a state machine that will modify its state each time you perform a change on it.
This change might be a transform : translate, scale, rotate.
Or affect the rendering : globalAlpha, globalCompositeOperation, shadows.
Or be a strokeStyle/fillStyle/font change.

Any time you change the context's state, it is a very good practice to save it before, and restore it after :

```
context.save();
 context.translate(.., ..);
 context.beginPath();
 context.move();
context.restore();
```

this way you end up with a context just as 'clean' after the call than before, no question asked.

For your code, you were quite close, for instance this code is quite ok (using random values) :

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // clear whole screen
  context.clearRect(0,0,600,600);  
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  // rotating step
  var angle = 2*Math.PI/cnt ; 
  // save context
  context.save();
  context.translate(300,300);
  for (var i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    context.rotate(angle);
    var val = values[i];    
    context.fillRect(-10, 100, 20, 80*val );
    values[i]+=(Math.random()-0.5)/20;
   }
  // restore now we're done.
  context.restore();       
}
```

you can try it here : 
http://jsbin.com/haxeqaza/1/edit?js,output

do not hesitate to comment // animate() and to launch animate2() instead, with 2 nice little trick.

:-)

Comment: OH GOD! I LOVE you thank you man! it works perfectly! here have a correct answer :)

Comment: I usually don't write code for people to copy paste, but it's up to you to do it of course.

Comment: @Winchestro: it's just the O.P. code, simplified, with save() before and restore() after...

Comment: I guess that's fine, my intuition just tells me as soon as someone sees the complete solution to a specific problem he completely stops thinking about how and why it works and this will just lead them into the next problem and if someone learns asking for a working solution is the most efficient solution... ya know.. :)

Comment: @Winchestro : I'm concerned about that point too. I think the O.P. had made significant efforts and was very close to the goal.
-> DavidCrisscReinberger : Glad i could help you build your disco-tool ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

All transformations add up, unless you use the contexts `.save()` and `.restore()` methods. They save the current transformation and restore it afterwards, so transformations in beteeen will not affect the next draw.

But since you want to rotate each bar by a fixed amount, I suggest you do exactly that and set the rotation for each bar so a fixed amount instead of increasing it and let the rotations add up.

Comment: i think you should just stick to explain save/restore, since it's O.P. first attempt at canvas, so transformation matrix or 'tricks' are not yet of big interest to him.

Comment: Alright. His code looks quite sophisticated, but I'll adjust my answer to get to the point faster :)

Comment: As you can see in the code

    c.translate(cx, cy);
    c.rotate(bar[i].rot);
    c.translate(-cx, -cy);

I always reset translate "the hardway"

Comment: mmmm... personally i prefer save(); for() { rotate(ctt); draw(); } restore(); to  for() { save(); rotate(i*ctte); draw(); restore(); } Maybe you should add pseudo-code to your post. Sorry if i'm being annoying.

Comment: Right now, it looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/230T0I0T0a11, I guess the problem is in the rotattion